# Hash table preformance structure

Tags: algorithm, hashtable, complexity-theory, load-factor

When a hash table reaches its maximum capacity, the number of free buckets should be increased to allow O(1) operations when a new value is inserted.

My question is: what is the optimal load factor of the hashtable to be increased to, When the load factor defined as the ratio betweens used and actual capacity - for example: 50 items in the table of 100 buckets gives load factor of 0.5.

I read that it should be increased by a factor of 2, however there were no justifications. Could you link some details regarding the suitble value.

Comment: You want to keep the load factor low. The logic is that if the load factor is low, you would have to probe fewer times to do a lookup. The thumb rule is to keep the load factor a small constant, to ensure the lookup operations are constant time operations. Now depending on how you resolve collisions, if you are using chaining, then load factor may be more than 1, but still keep it a constant. Whereas for Open Addressing, you have to have load factor less than 1, by definition. Still, try to keep it much much lower than 1. These are general guidelines.

Comment: So, in conclusion i should keep the load factor constant. there isn't definition says to increase the length of a hash table by 2 or by 3 or 10 (when need to reduce the load factor). is that correct? and thx anyway for pay attention.

Comment: Right, when it comes to hash table implementations, nothing is written in rock and stone, it all depends on the benchmark results you get from your hash table implementation and tuning it further dynamically.

Comment: Thx you for clearing that up :) I have looked for answer for very long time.